# Server 500 error with mod_deflate in .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-deflate

When I enable mod_deflate in .htaccess under Apache 2.2.23, I get a site wide 500 server error.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Don't compress certain content under Apache 2.x
<Location />
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI  \
    \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI  \
    \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|gz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \/(shipments)\.php no-gzip dont-vary
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \/(modules)\/ no-gzip dont-vary
</Location>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/* application/x-javascript application/javascript application/x-httpd-php application/rss+xml application/atom_xml

<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
    # properly handle requests coming from behind proxies
    Header append Vary User-Agent
</ifmodule>
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas what could be causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the "Location" tag. It does not belong there.

Answer (score 0):

A guess.....try removing the nested ifmodule construction and see what happens.

Comment: Might be better as a comment on the original post rather than an answer, unless you can flesh this out a bit.